# What is the difference between "Legacy Version" and "Stable Version"?

Tags: versioning

I am using JQuery Mobile and there are two available versions: A stable version and a legacy version. I am not familiar with the latter one.

What is a legacy version? or what is the difference with the stable version?

Which one is recommended to use in a production site?

Many thanks

Answer (score 52, accepted):

A legacy version is an old stable release that is still available (and probably supported) because someone might need it (e.g. plugin dependencies that don't work with the newest release), whereas the stable version is the most recent stable release (which will eventually become a legacy version).

So if there is no reason not to do so, just chose the stable version.