# Update Cent OS packages?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos

I just Installed Cent OS 6.5 and I am amazed with a few things.

Why the PHP version is only **5.3.3**, MySQL **5.1.73**, Apache **2.2.15**?

If I run the `yum` commands to update them no updates are found.

Is there a reason the default installation contains so old versions and how to update them to the latest one please?

Comment: My guess is that you need to add newer repositories, based on whether you're running 32 or 64 bit. On another point, the reason why you may have CentOS 6.5, but have older versions of software is simply based on the image file which your host uses to first install the software.

Comment: I run 64 bit. Can you please tell me more?

Comment: I run this on my Computer. I downloaded the image from there: http://www.centos.org/download/ a few hours ago

Comment: Redhat, (from which CentOS is derived from) is marketed and designed as a stable OS as indicated by the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512247/what-is-the-difference-between-legacy-version-and-stable-version). While the software version may look old you can rest assured that all security fixes from the newer versions of your software have likely been backported to your version.

Comment: I understand this but I need at least a 5.6 MySQL for performance reasons alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running these two commands should install a newer version of the EPEL repo, enabling you to install a newer version of PHP, etc, but you should find the repository which has the versions which you require.

```
 wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
 rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I did this, and then `yum install php` and says: `php-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version`

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

yum update php*

If you have rpm package then you can use rpm -U option to upgrade existing packages.